# do_convert_from_pkcs8: /dev/fd/63 is not a recognised public key format

Tags: ssh, openssl, ssh-keygen

I am trying to retrieve my PIV key using the following script:

`getPIVkey.sh`

```
NAME=`security find-certificate | grep PIV | sed 's;keychain:";;g' | sed 's;";;g'`
echo $NAME
ssh-keygen -i -m pkcs8 -f <(security find-certificate -p "$NAME" | openssl x509 -noout -pubkey)
```

on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.4. I get:

`./getPIVPub.sh`

```
keychain: PIV-Bill K Brown (piv)
security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.
    unable to load certificate
    140735828857800:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-22.50.2/libressl/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:704:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
    do_convert_from_pkcs8: /dev/fd/63 is not a recognised public key format
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a space in your first `sed` command, between `keychain:` and the quote. So your command to set the `NAME` variable should be

```
NAME=`security find-certificate | grep PIV | sed 's;keychain: ";;g' | sed 's;";;g'`
```

With the improved `sed` command, the (printed) value of `NAME` should no longer start with `keychain:` but just contain the name.

As a consequence of the wrong value in `NAME`, the second `security find-certificate` command fails, hence the output `The specified output could not be found in the keychain.`. The commands executed after that then fail as well.

FYI, the reason for the reference to `/dev/fd/63` is explained in the answer to the question [Why does process substitution result in a file called /dev/fd/63 which is a pipe?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156084/why-does-process-substitution-result-in-a-file-called-dev-fd-63-which-is-a-pipe)